# How to extract first 3 character from a name field

Tags: apex, soql, string

Is is possible to extract first 3 letters of last name using soql?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use just `SOQL`, you must create a formula field on the `SObject` in question.

```
LEFT(Last_Name__c, 3)
```

Comment: I think you mean "create a formula field on that sObject", is that right?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this on the Visualforce Page you can use Functions. For example `LEFT`:

> Returns the specified number of characters from the beginning of a
>   text string.

```
LEFT(Account.LastName, 3)
```

[Read more about functions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#LEFT)